# Flutter desktop payment gateway

Tags: flutter, payment-gateway, flutter-desktop

Currently, most payment gateway providers support 3 platforms (Android, IOS, Web) in the flutter, but have possible to use payment gateway on desktop applications. By using WebView or any possibility?